# Using mutate and grepl with multiple conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements, grepl, mutate

I'm attempting to use mutate and grepl to modify a column based on specific conditions in 2 other columns. One of those conditions is met by matching specific words in one of the columns. Both conditions have to be met. Below is a description of script example of what I'm trying to do:

```
df <- x %>% 
        mutate(col3 = ifelse(grepl(c("string1"), col1) & grepl(c("string5|string6|string7"), col2), 
                            "new_string",
                             col1))
```

When using grepl, OR (|) seems to be the only thing that works. I need both conditions to be true. I therefore need to use AND (&) or something of the sort.

Anyone might have a simple solution?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code and data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: this is a provisional answer. OP needs to provide more information.)

The code you have works, provided it matches the data you have. It would be helpful, as [Quinten has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77536557/using-mutate-and-grepl-with-multiple-conditions#comment136692870_77536557), if you provided sample data and an expected output.  But, to answer the question, of how to use "mutate and grepl with multiple conditions", *literally the way you did it is the answer*:

```
# generate sample data:
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = paste0("string", 1:2),
    col2 = paste0("string", 1:10))

df %>% 
    mutate(col3 = ifelse(grepl(c("string1"), col1) & grepl(c("string5|string6|string7"), col2), 
                        "new_string",
                            col1))
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2       col3
1  string1  string1    string1
2  string2  string2    string2
3  string1  string3    string1
4  string2  string4    string2
5  string1  string5 new_string
6  string2  string6    string2
7  string1  string7 new_string
8  string2  string8    string2
9  string1  string9    string1
10 string2 string10    string2
```

Comment: It works fine. I was pulling on the wrong column

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `case_when`? Here is another way to do it:

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    col3 = case_when(
      str_detect(col1, "string1") & str_detect(col2, "string5|string6|string7", perl = TRUE) ~ "new_string",
      TRUE ~ col1
    )
  )
```

Comment: In this particular case, with only one condition (a nested condition, but one nonetheless), `case_when` does npt show any advantage over ifelse